# How do Recursive menu in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have passed value on variable from controller to view page, and show the value in `foreach` loop. Now I want to do, when execute `foreach` loop, any value I want to pass in "**test**"   controller method.. I have a query defendant on this value.

A) Is there a way of getting the response of a controller from within a view

B) Is there a way of getting the response of a controller from within a controller method, so that I can push the result to the view?
My code so far is:

**First action on this method : (AccHeadController/create)**

```
public function create()
{
     $root = DB::table('chart_of_account')
        ->select('*')
        ->where('parent_id','=',0)
        ->get();
    return view('pages.createacchead')->with('level1', $root);
}
```

**And Pass level1 variable on view page (pages.createacchead) :**

```
 <fieldset>
     @foreach($level1 as $item)
       <ul>
          <li>
             <input type="radio" name="acchead" value="{{$item->id}}"> {{$item->title}}</br>                
          </li>
       </ul>
     @endforeach
</fieldset>
```

**how to pass   $item->id to AccHeadController test methode when execute foreach?**

> And here is AccHeadController/test method :

```
public function test($id){
     $root = DB::table('chart_of_account')
            ->select('*')
            ->where('parent_id','=',$id)
            ->get();
   }
```

Actually I want to show unlimited sub menu.

Comment: I think you can do it by self join

Comment: @Md. Sahadat Hossain, Self join return value but I can't rearrange it base on menu and submenu.

Comment: when you get the array with all item then you can rearrange the array with your logic